# Intuition for transition amplitude oscillations

Tags: quantum-field-theory, scattering, beyond-the-standard-model, scattering-cross-section

I am trying to develop some intuition for simulating scattering processes. Let $|i\rangle$ and $|f\rangle$ be some sensible initial and final scattering states. Assume they are not eigenstates of the full interacting Hamiltonian — for example, both could be superpositions of wave packets peaked at certain values of momentum.

What is our guess for how the transition amplitude $f(t)=|\langle f| \operatorname{e}^{-iH_{\mathrm{full}}t} |i \rangle|$ should look like? If we, say, did the Fourier transform of $f(t)$, what would we expect to see? How would it depend on the choice of $|i\rangle$, $|f\rangle$, and the spectrum of $H_{\mathrm{full}}$? (Ideally, I would like to know some non-perturbative statements.)

Comment: Hint: LSZ formalism